# How can I get multiple output from a list

Tags: python, list

I want to look into a text and return all  same values specified in a list. this is code I tried

```
def location (text):
for i in Locationlst:
    if i in text :
        return i
```

with this if I have text such as "I worked in London and now I returning to USA" and the list I specified is =["London", "USA", "UK"].
I return only London and what I want is both London and USA

Comment: Could you improve the question or add more code? I don't completely understand the problem.

Comment: use `yield` then `return`, once done, you can list all the elment from a generator

Comment: What is ´Locationlst` and where is it defined? Please add some details to your code and make an [mre]

Comment: `return [i for i in Locationlst if i in text]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `return`, you are returning from the function at that particular statement and therefore the loop is not run completely.

You need to use a list and append the elements to the list and return that list object instead.

```
def location (text):
    Locationlst = ["London", "USA", "UK"]
    res = []
    for i in Locationlst:
        if i in text :
            res.append(i)
    return res

print(location("I worked in London and now I returning to USA"))
```

Further, you can do the same in a single line with list comprehension as:

```
def location_0(text):
    Locationlst = ["London", "USA", "UK"]
    return [i for i in Locationlst if i in text]

print(location_0("I worked in London and now I returning to USA"))
```